# Not able to overwrite/delete an existing Service in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, web-service

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Server.

I have an existing service called xyz in a folder called DATA published using xyz.mxd. Now when I am trying to overwrite the existing service, it is giving me an error "ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service". So I thought to delete the service and create a new one, but it doesn't allow me to delete the service either and gives me an error "Access Denied" even though I have admin rights.

I checked the logs on ArcGIS Server Manager while trying to publish the service and the following error came up:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to rename old path 'E:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Data/OS.MapServer' to new path 'E:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Data/OS_201604151509.MapServer'.
at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.util.FileUtil.renameTo(FileUtil.java:81) 
at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.admin.services.ServiceManager.renameService(ServiceManager.java:856)
at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.admin.rest.services.FolderServlet.b(FolderServlet.java:444) at
```

I am not sure why it is trying to rename the file!!! The issue is with this particular folder because when I create a new service in this folder it again give an error.

On deletion, the following error comes:

```
Could not connect to the identity store as one or more of the connection parameters is incorrect. Verify that you can connect to the identity store outside of ArcGIS Server using the same parameters. [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the log level on server, then try again deleting again to see if you can get more details in the log?

Comment: Hi Kirk, I have updated my question with logs. Thanks, Astha

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.